# Facebook sharer.php not submitting content

Tags: facebook

I thought I had this nailed, but it isn't working properly...

The code below correctly launches a popup and correctly adds all the info I want it to, but when I click share, it only passes a link to my site, not the custom title or image...

```
<a class="facebook" target="_blank" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=300')" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=MY_TITLE&p[summary]=MY_SUMMARY&p[url]=MY_URL&p[images[0]=http://mydomain.com/image.jpg<img src="http://mydomain.com/new/images/facebook.png" width="32">
```

As I mentioned, I thought it worked OK as it displayed all the info correctly in the popup, but when shared on my page, it stripped everything out and only displayed a URL.

I have also tried adding the og:title, etc... in the  section, but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn;t pass the cirrect info despite it appearing in the Facebook popup correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have an error in you HTML tags!